# Como obtener registros distintos o que no sean iguales de dos tablas relacionadas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Antes que nada, gracias a todos por leerme.
Soy nuevo en esto y estoy atorado en una consulta. Tengo dos tablas que estan unidas por un id en comun. La tabla "Clientes" y la tabla "TiposCliente", el campo que hace match entre estas dos tablas es IdCliente

```
SELECT * FROM Clientes as A INNER JOIN TiposCliente AS B ON A.IdCliente=B.IdCliente
```

Con esta consulta logre sacar los registros que son iguales pero ahora necesito sacar los registros que no son iguales, o sea que no estan relacionados con IdCliente de la Tabla TiposCliente, intente usando un EXCEPT pero no funciona:

```
SELECT * FROM Clientes
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Clientes As A INNER JOIN TiposCliente As B ON A.nIdProveedor42=B.nIdProv42
```

Esta con sulta me arrojo un error "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Ese error te da pq las consultas no devuelven la misma cantidad de columnas, para que un operador de conjunto funcione ambas consultas tienen que tener la misma cantidad de columnas en el select

Comment: Prueba con `SELECT Clientes.* FROM Clientes As A INNER JOIN TiposCliente ....`, para el `EXCEPT`` las columnas de las tablas a comparar deben ser las mismas, y con el `inner`  esto no ocurre

Answer (score -1):

Aquí te arroja los `IdCliente` de `TiposCliente` que no están en la tabla `Clientes`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Clientes as A LEFT JOIN TiposCliente AS B ON A.IdCliente=B.IdCliente
WHERE B.IdCliente is null
```